# Is it possible to call procedure inside a view in snowflake?

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

i have below table and stored procedure.

```
D           | state   | temp
-------------------------------
2021-06-21  |New York |69
2021-06-22  |Texes    |70
```

#stored procedure

```
create or replace procedure get_state_based_on_temp(temp_value integer)
returns table(state string)
language sql
as
$$
declare
    res resultset default (select state from temp_table1 where temp <= :temp_value);
begin
    return table(res);
end;
$$;
```

i am trying to create a view below

```
create or replace view tem_result_view as select doc.d as date_in, view_temp.state from temp_table1 doc, table(get_state_based_on_temp(69)) as view_temp;
```

But it reurns below error

```
Unknown table function GET_STATE_BASED_ON_TEMP
```

i am able to call the function as

```
call get_state_based_on_temp(70);
```

which return the result.

Any solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

A procedure can not be called inside a view. UDFs / functions can be called inside a view.

Have you tried to use a SQL table function (UDTF)?

```
create or replace function get_state_based_on_temp(temp_value integer)
returns table (state varchar)
as
$$
select state from temp_table1 where temp <= temp_value
$$;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions-table.html

Comment: Hi @Gokhan, i tried the above approach, but still i see the function call return 'Unknown Function ' error.. which looks strange.
~~~
call get_state_based_on_temp(70)

~~~

Comment: @Hari in your question you said, you can call it using "call get_state_based_on_temp()" - This is a "procedure call". A function should be called as "select get_state_based_on_temp()"